# Which kind of cast is from Type* to void*?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, casting

In C++ for any data type I can do the following:

```
Type* typedPointer = obtain();
void* voidPointer = typedPointer;
```

which cast is performed when I assign `Type*` to `void*`? Is this the same as

```
Type* typedPointer = obtain();
void* voidPointer = reinterpret_cast<void*>( typedPointer );
```

or is it some other cast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a standard pointer conversion. Since it is a standard conversion, it doesn't require any explicit cast.

If you want to reproduce the behavior of that conversion with an explicit cast, it would be `static_cast`, not `reinterpret_cast`.

Be definition of `static_cast` given in 5.2.9/2, `static_cast` can perform all conversions that can be performed implicitly.

Answer (score 4):

From `Type*` to `void*` implicit conversion is available. You can use `static_cast` to clarify the intention of the code. <strike>For the reverse you require `reinterpret_cast`</strike>

**EDIT**: As per comment for the reverse also `static_cast` can be used. Tried a sample piece of code and it indeed compiles. Didn't knew that and always used reinterpret_cast to cast from a void*.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a cast, it is implicit conversion.  Casts are explicit by definition.  It is no more a cast than:

```
char c = 'a';
int i = c;
```

is.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same cast. Any pointer can be cast to a void-pointer.