# Which casting technique is better for doing casting from upper class to lower class in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, casting

i want to cast from upper class pointer to lower class i.e from the base class pointer to derived class pointer.

Should i use "Dynamic_cast" or "reinterpret_cast"? please advice me

Comment: You should remove the "qt" tag, since the question is not particularly Qt related ;)

Comment: Thanks ereOn.. i think hjhill has edited and removed the Qt tag :)
thanks hjhill

Comment: @Solitaire: why do you need to downcast? It's occasionally necessary, but it's also a smell (i.e. sign of a problematic design).

Comment: @outis:in my application, there is one API "QAbstractItemDelegate * QAbstractItemView::itemDelegate () ".I have listview, which inherits "QAbstractItemView",myview is listview object,if i do myview->itemDelegate (),i have to assign to my delegate pointer, i.e typecast is necessary.. so i thought its like upper cast to downwards.

Comment: @Solitaire: why can't you assign to a variable with type `QAbstractItemDelegate *`? What's missing from class `QAbstractItemDelegate`?

Comment: @outis:i have created a subclass of "QAbstractItemDelegate"
so i need pointer to my subclass.. i need to type cast it right?..
is not required you think.. i'm poor in this suggest if i am wrong?

Comment: @Solitaire: you only need to downcast to access non-virtual methods and members that aren't declared on the base class. If all you're doing is calling virtual methods declared declared in `QAbstractItemDelegate`, even pure virtual methods, there's no need for a cast.

Comment: @outis:ya.. i have declared a method in derived class, which is not a virtual function and non member function of base class.. in this case i am doing type cast.. is this right?

Comment: @Solitaire: in that case, yes, you'll need to cast. However, you might be able to design things to take better advantage of polymorphism so that the cast isn't necessary. Without seeing specifics, I couldn't say for certain what the better option is. Perhaps a new question is in order ("I have `X` I'm using it for Y. How can I rewrite `X` to get rid of the casting and make better use of polymorphism?", including code samples).

Comment: @outis:
ya in this case, i am also confused.. since QAbstractItemDelegate is a system class. i cant write my function out there and make it pure virtual. i have no much idea about this. only you can help me in this:)

Comment: @outis:
ya in this case, i am also confused.. since QAbstractItemDelegate is a system class. i cant write my function out there and make it pure virtual. i have no much idea about this. only you can help me in this:)

Comment: @Solitaire: you're right, brain fart. You don't have control over library classes, so you can't redesign the API. At that point, you're left with `dynamic_cast`, unless by some chance you don't really need to access that derived method (which you might not, depending on what you're trying to accomplish). Comments aren't the best place to determine this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use `reinterpret_cast` - either use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`. If you're sure that the pointer is to exactly that derived class object use `static_cast`, otherwise use `dynamic_cast` (that will require the base class to be polymorhic) and check the result to ensure that the pointer is indeed to the class you want.

Comment: you mean, for upward casting as well as downward casting, static_cast is better? or when do i have to use static_cast or dynamic_cast?

Comment: You don't need to use a cast at all for "upward casting". `Derived *dptr = something; Base *bptr = dptr;` works fine.

Comment: Ok, fine.. if i am sure that i am going to do upper cast, i will not use any casting, for downward casting always i preffer static_cast..

but what is the use of Dynamic_cast? when i have to use "reinterprit_cast too?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is for when you don't know whether the thing pointed to by your `Base*` really is a `Derived` object, and you want to find out (and get a `Derived*` pointer if so). It's rarely needed. `reinterpret_cast` should never be used for casting between related pointer types. In certain circumstances (such as multiple inheritance) it gives the "wrong" answer, for instance gives you a `Derived*` pointer that will crash if you use it as a `Derived*`.

Comment: In case of upcast the implicit conversion that "just works" is in fact the static_cast - see this great answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198255/which-kind-of-cast-is-from-type-to-void/2205137#2205137.

Comment: @sharptooth: well, it has the same effect as the static_cast, because static_cast is defined to be able to perform standard conversions: compare 4.10/3 with 5.2.9/2. The reason I say you don't need a cast is just that a cast is by definition an explicit conversion, and this is an implicit conversion. But yes, static_casts between types that can be implicitly converted, and implicit conversions, are in fact the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you know about the pointer.

If you know for **sure** that the pointer you have is of a child type, you can `static_cast<>` it safely.

If you don't know for sure, just go with `dynamic_cast<>` but this has a cost and is slower.

Answer (score 2):

reinterpret_cast<> is a last resort and should be avoided.

In Qt, if casting between QObjects, use qobject_cast<>. It's semantically like dynamic_cast but has no issues with dll boundaries etc.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Ereon's answer: And if you do not know the type use dynamic_cast to do a run time type check by catching the bad_cast exception.

Comment: But he will get a null pointer if it's not of the dynamic_cast type.