# Factory methods in derived classes

Tags: c++, polymorphism, factory-pattern, dynamic-cast

I have two kinds of messages: `MessageA` and `MessageB`, both derived from abstract class `IMessage` containing pure virtual method `std::string toString()`. So i can convert each message to its string representation with pointer to the base class. That's fine. However, i need somehow to construct message (concrete type of message) from the string, for example:
`MessageA* msg = [something].fromString( str )`. I would like to get NULL if given string isn't suitable for construction of `MessageA`. I can see two approaches to this task:

a) `MessageFactory` with `dynamic_cast`

```
    class MessageFactory
    {
        IMessage* fromString( const std::string& str );
    };

    ...
    MessageFactory mf;
    MessageA* msg = dynamic_cast< MessageA* >( mf.fromString( str ) );
    if ( msg ) { ... }
```

However, this uses dynamic_cast which i would like to avoid.

b) factory method in each derived class

```
static MessageA* fromString( const std::string& str )
{
    return stringIsOk( str ) ? new MessageA() : NULL;
}
```

Is there any better solution? Should i change something in general design? Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Sometime i know what kind of message i should get from string, i.e.

```
void sendRequest()
{
 ...
 std::string response;
 MessageA* msg = fromString( response );
 // here i should only check if string is valid for MessageA
}
```

but sometime i don't know what will come to me:

```
void processMessage( const std::string& str )
{
     IMessage* msg = fromString( str );
     if ( msg )
     {
         MessageA* msgA = dynamic_cast< MessageA* >( msg );
         if ( msgA )
         ...
     } 
}
```

Comment: You really need it to cast to `MessageA*` ? `IMessage*` is not sufficient?

Comment: This looks like abuse. If you already know that you want a `MessageA` and only a `MessageA`, you can write a straight-forward parsing function (ideally returning `boost::optional<MessageA>`). The polymorphic hierarchy seems unnecessary.  A typical factory would return an `IMessage *`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I need to receive different kinds of messages. Sometime i can expect its type, sometime not. Message handling mechanism should process each kind of message differently.

Comment: Can you try to make where you use it a virtual function declared in the interface? Then you can just use it through the interface

Comment: @Kael You can put the differences into the IMessage vía virtual methods, so you don't need the concrete type. If you don't want to put the logic into the message classes, use the visitor/double dispatch pattern.

Comment: @Kael: that may well be, but the particular situation you describe doesn't call for runtime polymorphism. It's a straight-up question whether a string is parsable as a Foo or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make all classes derived from `IMessage` register themselves (or rather a specific factory) with a `MessageFactory` class statically at program start. This can be achieved by using some static instance. The `IMessage` interface then needs to have a pure virtual method `canConstructFrom(string&)` such that when a string comes in, you pass that to the `MessageFactory` and the factory will find out which of the derived classes can be constructed from that string and instantiate the correct one.

Comment: Thank you, this is nice solution. I am in same situation that is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758449/is-my-method-for-avoiding-dynamic-cast-faster-than-dynamic-cast-itself